# Datos de array se pierden javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Guardo los datos de una peticion ajaz con push en 2 arrays, pero cuando quiero acceder a los datos de los respectivos arrays no me aparecen :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "cargar_datos_reporteria_actividad.php",
    data: parametros,
    type : 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        var datos=JSON.parse(data);
        $.each(datos, function(index, val) {            
            duracion_minutos.push(val.duracion_minutos);
            fechas.push(val.fecha);
        });
        // SOLO DESDE QUI PUEDO ACCEDER A LOS DATOS ALMACENADOS CON PUSH
    }
});
```

Cabe recalcar que los array los tengo de manera global,fuera del metodo ajax no puedo acceder a lo que guarde con push.

```
var duracion_minutos=[];
var fechas=[];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu Confusión está en como funciona la parte **asíncrona** de javascript.

Siendo bien general, `$.ajax({...})` es asíncrono pues no espera a que tu server php le responda para avanzar a la siguiente línea de código, sino que sólo confirma de que envió la petición (sin saber si le van a responder, o qué cosa siquiera) y luego ejecuta lo que sea escribiste en la función `success: function(data){...}` dentro de los parámetros de `$.ajax`.

Te recomiendo usar una función que englobe lo que necesites hacer post-petición para que puedas pasárselo bien tu función `success`

```
function renderizar(duracion_minutos, fechas) {
    // Usar los arreglos para algo
    document.getElementById("fechasCant").text = fechas.length
}
$.ajax({
    url: "cargar_datos_reporteria_actividad.php",
    data: parametros,
    type : 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        var duracion_minutos=[];
        var fechas=[];
        var datos=JSON.parse(data);
        $.each(datos, function(index, val) {            
            duracion_minutos.push(val.duracion_minutos);
            fechas.push(val.fecha);
        });
        renderizar(duracion_minutos, fechas) // Llamar lo renderizado post respuesta ajax
        
    }
});
```